# php form handling multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, forms, if-statement, checkbox

I'm new to PHP form handling and I've handled it pretty well- apart from dealing PHP with Checkboxes.

The problem I have is I can't seem to echo out the correct 3 answers from my question. I would complete the form on my quiz ticking the correct three check boxes and for some reason PHP output's saying I have entered the wrong answer! Hope you can help, any answers will be much appreciated! :)

Here is my form and my question:

```
    <p> 22. What professional golfers have won the masters?</p>

<input type="checkbox" name="golfer" value="a">Tiger Woods<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="golfer" value="b">Phil Mickelson<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="golfer" value="c">Lee Westwood<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="golfer" value="d">Bubba watson<br />
```

And here is my PHP, I'm sure it is completely wrong but hopefully you know what I'm trying to achieve:

```
if ($golfer == "a" && "b" && "d") {
    echo "That's the right answer, Tiger Woods, Phil Mickelson and Bubba Watson have all won the Masters.";
} else {
    echo "That's the wrong answer. Lee Westwood has not won a major."; 
}
```

?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<input type="checkbox" name="golfer[]" ...
```

Then `$golfer` will be an array in PHP and you can compare with the correct values

The following PHP code will check if the submitted answer is `'a', 'b', 'd'`

```
sort($golfer);
$correct = array('a', 'b', 'd');

if ($golfer== $correct) {
    echo "That's the right answer, Tiger Woods, Phil Mickelson and Bubba Watson have all won the Masters.";
}
```

Comment: Never had these problems with Perl back in ye olde days when all yer intarwebs was powered by steam!

Comment: Still confused, sorry guys I'm very new to this! I have so far: foreach($golfer as $g) {}.... What do I do now?

Comment: I updated the answer, to give you a starting point about validating the different answers

Answer (score 0):

Make check boxes as an array

```
<input type="checkbox" name="golfer[]" value="a">Tiger Woods<br /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="golfer[]" value="b">Phil Mickelson<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="golfer[]" value="c">Lee Westwood<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="golfer[]" value="d">Bubba watson<br />
```

After form submission

```
// The array will only contain the checked value of forms
foreach($golfer as $g) {
   // can use checkbox value here
}
```